# php to ajax textarea variable not showing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been trying to send a variable from php to AJAX, and it used to work before, and suddenly it does not. I've been trying to understand why for the past few hours, reading about passing variable with no luck.

For some reason i cannot get the textarea into my ajax and post it to the rest of the application. It gives me an empty alert, but `var name = $("input[name='name']").val();` alerts correctly.

here is the html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/_data/js/addreply.js"></script>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenid" value="6" />
    <div id="writeCommTxt" >
        <textarea name="text" cols="90" rows="12" class="txtclassic" ></textarea>                            
        <div id="writeCommCapt">
            <div id="writeCommCaptSub"><input type="submit" name="postcomm" value="Submit" class="subclassic" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the AJAX in a separate file.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$(".subclassic").click(function (){
    var id = $("input[name='hiddenid']").val();
    var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
    var text = $(".txtclassic").val(); //i also tried to add textarea['text'].val() with no success.
    var capt = $("input[name='captcha']").val();
    alert(text); //it alerts an empty window.
    if (name != "" && text != ""){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/article/add_reply/" + id,
          data: {
              rename: name,
              retxt: text,
              recapt: capt
          },
          success: function (data){
           ...
          }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I noticed you mentioned that it use to work, so my question is what has changed since the last time it was known to work?

Comment: I did a lot of backend changes, which I wasn't expecting to have any impact on the frond end. I have no idea what it could be seriously. Why do i get an empty alert.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran i tried that too, and it give me undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add id attribute to textarea as follows.

```
<textarea name="text1" id="text1" cols="90" rows="12" class="txtclassic" ></textarea>
```

now access value  like this

```
var text = $('#text1').val();;
```

Comment: That worked! Could you explain why it works with an ID and not with a class?

Comment: probably because other elements have the same class name "txtclassic" and jquery uses the first one it finds with the val() function

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/irodig/1/)**

Why don't you use id?
In your case, I guess it is:

```
$('textarea[name="text"]').val();
```

Comment: tried that, it doesn't seem to work i get an empty alert, and when used with `$("input[name='text']")` i get an undefined alert

Comment: Then, try it from chrome console, whether you can reach to it.

Comment: you cant use `$("input[name='text']")` it has to be textarea `$("textarea[name='text']")`

Comment: no... didn't work with both things input/textarea without empty text. The example below works and I'm interested as to why when used as a class it didn't and when used as an ID it did.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function?
Put all the input controls in between a `<form>` tag give it an id and then call the serialize function on that element

```
<form id="myform">
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenid" value="6" />
        <div id="writeCommTxt" >
            <textarea name="text" cols="90" rows="12" class="txtclassic" ></textarea>                            
        <div id="writeCommCapt">
            <div id="writeCommCaptSub"><input type="submit" name="postcomm" value="Submit" class="subclassic" /></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Then in your script have

```
var myFormData = jQuery("#myform").serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/article/add_reply/" + id,
          data: myFormData,
          success: function (data){
           ...
          }
        });
```

As for the the original problem, you might have other elements with the class "txtclassic", and if so it will grab the first one it finds and try to get its value (if its not a input control it will return nothing)